# Strange VM Budget Exceeded Error

Tags: android, memory

I'm making a game that uses a lot of bitmaps for the images, and all of them are needed at any given time. When the game starts, the first thing I do is decode all the images. As of late I've been getting the dreaded "bitmap exceeds VM budget" error, but I don't understand why I'm getting it for the following reasons:

1. The image files that are being used are in total around 3.5 MB, which I believe shouldn't be a problem.
2. The error has come and gone even though the code was hardly changed at all. Reverting code back to when the error didn't occur still has the error occurring.
3. Despite attempts to reduce memory usage, including ones that are mentioned here like BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize, LogCat still shows the error appearing at the same line of code. That line of code is another image decoding just like all the others.

Anyone have any thoughts on why this might be occurring? If you must, below is example code of what I'm doing:

```
public GameThread(SurfaceHolder sHolder, Context context, Handler handler)
{
    background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg);
    // Code repeated for other images, crashing at one of them towards the end.
}
```

Comment: 3.5 MB sounds like compressed files on disk. When you load them into memory they are getting uncompressed and take space according to the number of pixels. If you use `ARGB_8888` as an image format (default for `BitmapFactory`) internally, each pixel takes 4 bytes. Example: Random photo from my sdcard has 1010 kB on disk compressed into jpeg at 1552x2592, but uncompressed it should take (1552*2592*4) bytes, which is around 15 MB.

Comment: Is...is there any way around that?

Comment: Basically the answer is: Depends. In Java, no. You have this fixed limit (down to 16 MB on some devices if I remember correctly). All you can do here is test which images you really need at a given point in time and only load these to keep the memory as free as possible. What you also can do is using the NDK to load the pictures and reference them from java via JNI. The limits don't apply to memory allocated in native code. But I can't tell you much more, never done that myself. You have to use some C for this. Try googling around.

Comment: Well alextsc, you basically answered my question, though I cannot accept comments as answers.

Comment: Posted and reformatted a bit. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. The image files that are being used are in total around 3.5 MB, which
>      I believe shouldn't be a problem.

3.5 MB sounds like compressed files on disk. When you load them into memory they are getting uncompressed and take space according to the number of pixels. If you use `ARGB_8888` as an image format (default for `BitmapFactory`) internally, each pixel takes 4 bytes.

**Example:** A random photo from my SD-card has 1010 kB on disk compressed into JPEG at a 1552x2592 resolution, but uncompressed it should take `(1552*2592*4)` bytes, which is around 15 MB.

### Is there a way around this limit?

Basically the answer is: Depends. In Java, no. You have this fixed limit (down to 16 MB on some devices if I remember correctly). All you can do here is test which images you really need at a given point in time and only load these to keep the memory as free as possible. What you also can do is using the NDK to load the pictures and reference them from java via JNI. The limits don't apply to memory allocated in native code. But I can't tell you much more, never done that myself. You have to use some C for this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe some Bitmaps are being recreated over and over and not being recycle(). Android has ~20-25 Bitmap VM.